# ストアドプロシジャーを PyMySQL から実行できない

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

ストアドプロシジャーを作成する SQL を AWS Lambda python で実行したいのですが

ストアドプロシジャーを初めて使うので
後述のような最低限のテストコードを書いてローカルで実行してみると文法エラーがでます
(Lambda 上でも同じエラーになります）

```
  sql ='''
create temporary table test (
  x int
)
'''
```

だと動くので接続情報や実行環境は問題ないと思われますし
同じ MySQL をみてる workbench に SQL の中だけ
貼り付けると動くので SQL の中も問題ないはずなのですが

何が悪いのでしょうか

```
#-*- using:utf-8 -*-

import pymysql
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('mysql.ini', encoding='utf-8')
config = config['DEFAULT']

mysql = pymysql.connect(host    =config['db_host'],
                        user    =config['db_username'],
                        password=config['db_password'],
                        db      =config['db_name'],
                        charset =config['db_charset'])

with mysql.cursor() as cursor:
  sql ='''
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION echo(n int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
  RETURN n;
END//
DELIMITER ;
'''
  cursor.execute(sql)
```

エラーメッセージ

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //\nCREATE FUNCTION echo(n int)\nRETURNS int\nBEGIN\n  RETURN n;\nEND//\nDEL' at line 1")
```

python 3.7 です

Comment: 参考: [Create function through MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/745575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ややこしいのですが、DELIMITER はクエリではなくて mysql クライアントのコマンドなのです。
mysql コマンドが `;` をクエリの区切りと認識してしまうため、それを別の文字列に置き換えるのが DELIMITER です。

なので、DELIMITER を書かずに、そのまま

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION echo(n int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
  RETURN n;
END
```

とだけ書けばいいと思います。